# Is it possible to change isolation level at datasource setting file in coldfusion?

Tags: coldfusion

In coldfusion, is it possible to set isolation level to 'read uncommitted' from the default isolation level 'read committed' at datasource level...

I think this can be done from datasource file in internal files where each datasource connection setting resides.

Please share your thoughts on this.

Thanks,
Sj

Comment: You might want to retag this as a JDBC question (and mention what sort of DB you're connecting to!) and see if it can be done via JDBC. It can't be done via CF as far as I knows.

Comment: Ditto. I do not believe it can be controlled through the dsn config files. In terms of CF, AFAIK, the closest you could get is use the [`Validation Query`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/Admin/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbf364104-7fe5.html) setting to run a `set transaction isolation level ...` command.

Comment: You can do this per transaction in CF, as Leigh mentioned. You didn't mention which db you are trying to accomplish this on. You have some options on the db side to turn the snapshot off, or try row level versioning, etc. It depends on what you are trying to accomplish however.

Answer (score 2):

You have several options:

1. Doing it on the database itself (for example in MS Sql Server you can set the default isolation level)
2. Doing it on the datasource (as you asked) was available in CF 6 via the xml but I would highly advise against it even if it was still supported
3. Using table hints in your SQL.

Since isolation deals with a transaction it makes more sense to either set the default READ in the database or to specify it via `<cftransaction isolation="read_uncommitted"...>`

If you need it to apply to all statements such as allowing snapshot reads then apply the default isolation in the DB itself.  [Here's a good overview](http://www.brentozar.com/archive/2013/01/implementing-snapshot-or-read-committed-snapshot-isolation-in-sql-server-a-guide/) and steps on how to set that up.

If you want to read uncommitted from a particular table (doesn't sound like it) then use table hints such as

```
SELECT * FROM LargeDataSet WITH (NOLOCK)
```

keeping in mind that it's a hint and that the engine isn't forced to adhere to it.

Generally if you need to read uncommitted data then it means you're experience read blocking that you may need to consider some architectural changes (been there, done that) or change your default to snapshot mode (pros and cons with that approach as well)

Good luck!